# CSV::MalformedCSVError: Illegal quoting in line 1 with SmarterCSV

Tags: csv, smartercsv

I have an issue, when trying to process a csv file, using SmarterCSV.
The error I get is -

```
CSV::MalformedCSVError: Illegal quoting in line 1
```

This is where the code I use to process the csv file

```
SmarterCSV.process(file_path)
```

I have gone through similar questions. But no where I find a good fit that could help me.

I tried to resolve it using some options of [SmarterCSV](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/smarter_csv/1.0.19) such as -

*:remove_empty_values, :remove_empty_hashes* etc. But in vain.

I welcome the suggestions or refactoring to make this work? Thanks all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to illegal Unicode characters inside your file.

You can process file with Unicode characters with

```
f = File.open(file_path, "r:bom|utf-8"); data = SmarterCSV.process(f); f.close
```

here data will contain parsed data.

Also refer official documentation on this:https://github.com/tilo/smarter_csv#notes-about-file-encodings

Comment: Thank you, but I think this isn't a good way to read a large file. What is the way to read large file?