# Logstash MalformedCSVError: Illegal quoting in line | how to configure logstash conf to read multi column mutiline CSV?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

Already went through [CSV::MalformedCSVError: Illegal quoting in line 1 with SmarterCSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29717506/csvmalformedcsverror-illegal-quoting-in-line-1-with-smartercsv)
    and [Rescue CSV::MalformedCsvError: Illegal quoting in line n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37277866/rescue-csvmalformedcsverror-illegal-quoting-in-line-n)
    None of them addresses my problem.

I'm facing problem while basic integration of CSV conf with Log Stash:

```
    input {
      file {
        path => "/softwares/imews_customer_wallet_details.csv"
        start_position => "beginning"
      }
    }
    filter {
      csv {
        columns => ["imiles_wallet_id","creation_date","gcid_cod","total_imiles","is_active"]
        separator => ","
      }
      date {
        match => ["creation_date", "dd-MM-yy"]
        target => "creation_date"
      }
    }
    output {
      elasticsearch {
        action => "index"
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        index => "ime_customers"
      }
    }
```

Error Stack prints following line on loop:

```
    [2020-03-02T13:36:51,968][WARN ][logstash.filters.csv     ][another_test] Error parsing csv {:field=>"message", :source=>"{\"level\":\"DEBUG\",\"timeUTC\":\"Mon Feb 24 08:05:20 UTC 2020\",\"timeUnix\":1582531520800,\"appID\":\"TEST\",\"hub\":\"CI\",\"environment\":\"NONE\",\"host\":\"Yashpal3150153\",\"logMessage\":\"http-outgoing-1 << Content-Type: application/x-amz-json-1.0\",\"threadID\":\"SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1\",\"cdll_version\":\"6.5.0\"}\r", :exception=>#<CSV::MalformedCSVError: Illegal quoting in line 1.>}
```

What am I Missing, what's wrong here?

Update:

CSV:

```
    125,IME,"14-11-19","14-11-19",IME,"14-11-19",gcid3,100,TRUE
    124,IME,"14-11-19","14-11-19",IME,"14-11-19",gcid2,100,TRUE
    123,IME,"14-11-19","14-11-19",IME,"14-11-19",gcid1,252,TRUE
```

**Update**:
Pipeline:

```
     - pipeline.id: another_test
       queue.type: persisted
       path.config: "/softwares/logstash-7.6.0/config/*.conf"
```

config contains: 
[image]
My conf I mentioned is: `cust.conf`

Also, I updated the cust.conf to:

```
    input {
      file {
        path => "D:/softwares/imews_customer_wallet_details.csv"
        start_position => "beginning"
      }
    }
    filter {
      csv {
        columns => ["imiles_wallet_id","creation_date","gcid_cod","total_imiles","is_active"]
        separator => ","
        codec => plain
        convert => {
          "imiles_wallet_id" => "integer"
          "is_active" => "boolean"
          "creation_date" => "date"
          "gcid_cod" => "string"
          "total_imiles" => "integer"
        } 
      }
    }
    output {
      elasticsearch {
        action => "index"
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        index => "ime_customers"
      }
    }
```

Now the Error is:

````
    LogStash::Error: Don't know how to handle `Java::JavaLang::IllegalStateException` for `PipelineAction::Create<another_test>`
              create at org/logstash/execution/ConvergeResultExt.java:109
                 add at org/logstash/execution/ConvergeResultExt.java:37
      converge_state at D:/softwares/logstash-7.6.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:339
    [2020-03-04T18:20:05,345][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] An exception happened when converging configuration {:exception=>LogStash::Error, :message=>"Don't know how to handle `Java::JavaLang::IllegalStateException` for `PipelineAction::Create<another_test>`", :backtrace=>["org/logstash/execution/ConvergeResultExt.java:109:in `create'", "org/logstash/execution/ConvergeResultExt.java:37:in `add'", "D:/softwares/logstash-7.6.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:339:in `block in converge_state'"]}
    [2020-03-04T18:20:05,397][FATAL][logstash.runner          ] An unexpected error occurred! {:error=>#<LogStash::Error: Don't know how to handle `Java::JavaLang::IllegalStateException` for `PipelineAction::Create<another_test>`>, :backtrace=>["org/logstash/execution/ConvergeResultExt.java:109:in `create'", "org/logstash/execution/ConvergeResultExt.java:37:in `add'", "D:/softwares/logstash-7.6.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:339:in `block in converge_state'"]}
    ```
````

Comment: Can you show the first 2-3 lines of your CSV as well?

Comment: @Val updated in the question itself.

Comment: If you check your error message, you'll see that the message that Logstash tries to parse doesn't really look like CSV, it looks like JSON. Are you sure about your input, what files you're reading and their content?

Comment: Yes sir, that is the exact Input, In fact I thought the `-`s in the date might cause the issue, that's why I wrapped the dates in  double `""`

Comment: @Val can you mention the part of error which gives the idea that the input looks like a JSON?

Comment: `{:field=>"message", :source=>"{\"level\":\"DEBUG\",\"timeUTC\":\"Mon Feb 24 08:05:20 UTC 2020\",\"timeUnix\":1582531520800,\"appID\":\"TEST\",\"hub\":\"CI\",\"environment\":\"NONE\",\"host\":\"Yashpal3150153\",\"logMessage\":\"http-outgoing-1 << Content-Type: application/x-amz-json-1.0\",\"threadID\":\"SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1\",\"cdll_version\":\"6.5.0\"}\r"`

Comment: As per my knowledge that a standard error response. Not related to input.

Comment: That line comes from the `logstash.filters.csv` filter and is labelled WARN. This means that something coming from an input is not CSV-ready.

Comment: @Val But the file contains only lines that I have shown, not even a blank new line at the end, you may try the given input at your system as well, the error should be the same.

Comment: You know of a host named "Yashpal3150153"?

Comment: How do you start Logstash? Command-line or as a service? In the latter case, do you have other input files in your configuration folder?

Comment: Yes, that's my host, I'm using CLI cmd `.\bin\logstash.bat`. Other input file is sample logs file which contains log, and got successfully uploaded to ES, logs can be seen on Kibana.

Comment: How do you point your Logstash instance at your configuration file?

Comment: Through the pipeline, updated in description

Comment: Ok, what are all the files you have in `/softwares/logstash-7.6.0/config/*.conf` ? Do you have several `*.conf` files?

Comment: Attached a screenshot

Comment: Simply start logstash with `bin/logstash -f /softwares/logstash-7.6.0/config/cust.conf` how does it work?

Comment: @Val thanks, the error disappeared, the index was added, but no data is shown from the CSV.

Comment: One more question, why isn't it executing it from the pipeline?

Comment: Ok, the problem was that you have several configuration files (i.e. `*.conf`) and probably several input. When using a pipeline, note that all configuration files are "merged" into a single configuration (with potentially several sources, filters and outputs)

Comment: Yeah, that can be the probable reason, But I'm not able to see the data on Kibana. Also @Val, would you take a minute to add this resolution as answer so that I can can mark that correct answer. We did a lot of grooming there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By starting Logstash with a pipeline definition `/softwares/logstash-7.6.0/config/*.conf` you probably have many configuration files that interfere with each other (i.e. several different inputs, filters and outputs). All those configuration files are merged into a single configuration.

Read [this article](https://www.elastic.co/blog/how-to-create-maintainable-and-reusable-logstash-pipelines) in order to learn how to best organize your Logstash pipelines.
In the meantime, you can simply start your Logstash from the command-line like this:

```
bin/logstash -f /softwares/logstash-7.6.0/config/cust.conf
```